# Correct usage of C++ template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I've some trouble to make use of template template parameters. Here is a very simplified example:

```
template <typename T> 
struct Foo {
  T t;
};

template <template <class X> class T>
struct Bar {
  T<X> data;
  X x;
};

int main()
{
  Bar<Foo<int>> a;
}
```

The compiler (g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2) reports the following error:

```
main.cpp:8:5: error: ‘X’ was not declared in this scope
   T<X> data;
     ^

main.cpp:8:6: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   T<X> data;
      ^
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *So I would like so make use of something like `Bar<Foo<>>`*

```
template <typename T = int> 
struct Foo {
  T t;
};

template <typename T>
struct Baz {
  T t;
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar;

template <template <typename> class T, typename X>
struct Bar<T<X>> {
  T<X> data;
  X x;
};

int main()
{
  Bar<Foo<>> a;
  Bar<Baz<float>> b;
}
```

Comment: Okay, it looks fine and compiles (I've just forgotten -std=c++11 flag). But I don't understand your solution. Why is the very first declaration of `Bar` required?

Comment: @ThomasWitkowski it's *primary template*, so that I can specialize it for `struct Bar<T<X> >` case. it is left incomplete intentionally, so that it is not instantiated with type other than one-parameter template

Answer (score 8):

```
template <typename T> 
struct Foo {
  T t;
};

template <template <class> class T, class X>
struct Bar {
  T<X> data;
  X x;
};

int main()
{
  Bar<Foo, int> a;
}
```

Comment: @Bathsheba Probably because I left no explanation. But it's so weird to me that I just can't put it into English words.

Comment: This solution is a little bit unsatisfactory. The point is, that in the real example `Foo` has a default for the template parameter, say `int`. So I would like so make use of something like `Bar<Foo<>>`. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

In

```
template <template <class X> class T>
```

The template type parameter `X` is not a template parameter to the outermost template: it is a template parameter to the innermost template. It's rather similar to

```
int foo(int (*bar)(int x))
{
    int y = x;  // compiler error
}
```

which doesn't work since the function takes a single argument, `bar`: there is no argument `x`.

Depending upon what you are truly trying to do, you could add the second template parameter, with something like

```
template <typename X, template <typename> class T >
struct Bar
{
    // ...
};
```

you can keep the declaration with a single type parameter, but pattern match to give a partial specialization that would define the class in the example context

```
template <typename T>
struct Bar;

template <typename X, template <typename> class T >
struct Bar<T<X>>
{
    // ...
};
```

you could modify `Foo` to have a useful nested type, and grab it that way

```
template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    using X = T::value_type;
};
```

or you could define a metafunction that extracts a template parameter from a template type, and get it that way:

```
template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    using X = get_parameter<T>;
};
```

The most flexible is the last version, except rather than a metafunction that extracts template arguments, you would declare a `get_bar_parameter` function, and define a partial specialization that extracts the template parameter from a `Foo<X>` (or a `T<X>`). That way, if you ever decide in the future to use `Bar` with classes where the right value of `X` *isn't* computed that way, you can do so by giving an appropriate specialization for `get_bar_parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// method 1
template <typename T> 
struct Foo {
  typedef T Type;
  T t;
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
  T data;
  typename T::Type x;
};

// method 2
template <typename T>
struct Hack
{
  T t;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeOf
{
  typedef struct UnknownType Type;
};

template<>
struct TypeOf< Hack<int> >
{
  typedef int Type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Baz {
  T data;
  typename TypeOf<T>::Type X;
};

int main()
{
  Bar< Foo<int> > a;
  Baz< Hack<int> > b;
  return 0;
}
```

In method 1 information is provided with nested type.  This requires changing original class.

In method 2 this information is provided with specialization of another template.

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Typically you want to provide an explanation to accompany your code when posting an answer